# How do I know what kind of interface my wireless device uses?

Tags: wireless

I am troubleshooting ubuntu wireless in 12.04. The [wireless](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Devices) guide says "If no wireless devices are listed, the next step will depend on the type of interface your device uses."

How can I tell what type of interface my device uses? I am on a ThinkPad dual booting into windows 8. In windows 8 it says connection name=wifi, network adapter=2x2 11b/g/n Wir Transport Name = \Device\Tcpip_someLongGuidInHex

Answer (score 0):

I believe it refers to a PCI device, a USB device, a PCMCIA device, etc. If your device is built in to the laptop, it is most likely a PCI device and can be identified from a terminal command:

```
lspci -nn
```

You can list only devices of the class 'wireless networking' with:

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

The pipe symbol | is on the right side of my US keyboard on the same key with backslash.

In a very few cases, an internal wireless device is attached to an internal USB bus and can be identified with:

```
lsusb
```